# Applescript Mouse Click Reference absolute or relative

Tags: applescript

I want applescript to click on a certain position within a Google Chrome tab.

I am using this code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click at {175, 300} 
    end tell
end tell
```

What is the zero reference for the coordinate?
a) the monitor upper left corner or
b) the upper left corner of the Google Chrome window

I am on a Mac and use the shift cmd 4 combination to determine the cursor coordinate.

Thanks for any leads

Answer (score 1):

The **`click at {x, y}`** command of *System Events* will interpret `{x, y}` relative to the top-left corner of the screen, which is `{0, 0}`.  This is the case regardless of whether or not you target the command at a specific process (e.g. Google Chrome) or omit a target process altogether, i.e.

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to click at {175, 300}
```

The target determines the set of UI elements that the `click at` command can interact with, the latter example above defining the set of all UI elements visible on the screen.